# Distance between two nodes in a tree algorithm issue

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, nodes

I need to calculate the distance between two nodes in a tree.
I implemented the general formula:

```
Dist(n1,n2) = Dist(root,n1), Dist(root,n2) - 2*Dist(root,lca)
```

The code works for most of input, but if I try with (father, son) I get the wrong distance.
Here is my code:

```
public static int distance(Tree t, Node<String> node1, Node<String> node2)
{
    Node<String> lca = lca(node1, node2);
    //This if statement is when the input contains the root itself
    //this means that the distance is simply from the node and the root
    if(lca==null)
    {
        // the function getNumberOfAncestors returns exactly the distance between a generic node and the root, since I count parent by parent and so on.
        return node1.getNumberOfAncestors() + node2.getNumberOfAncestors();
    }

    return node1.getNumberOfAncestors() + node2.getNumberOfAncestors() - 2*distance(t, t.getRoot(), lca);
}
```

For the simple tree:

```
   A
 B   C
D E F G
```

We know that the Dist(C,G)=1, but my algorithm returns 3.
Any ideas?

Comment: Try out BFS. It's dead simple, well-documented, and will also give you the shortest path between a start node and any other node.

Comment: For debugging you should first of all print node1.getNumberOfAncestors(), node2.getNumberOfAncestors() and distance(t, t.getRoot(), lca).  To see if all 3 values are correct.  Edit: Also is there a reason why you don't use getNumberOfAncestors() on lca?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the implementation of the method lca so we can check if it works the right way. I'm pretty sure `distance` returns 3 because `lca(node1, node2)` is null. In this case 
`lca == null` is true and the method returns

`node1.getNumberOfAncestors() + node2.getNumberOfAncestors()`

which is basically

`node1.getNumberOfAncestors() = 1` for C +

`node2.getNumberOfAncestors() = 2` for G = 3